# Program crashes. Deciphering the error message

Tags: java, c, multithreading, macos, debugging

I just released a multi-language image processing software as an ImageJ plugin. It has components written in Jython, C and Java. The C programs are called through the JNA. The software runs perfectly on my Macbook pro OSX Yosemite (64-bit). I sent the program to a long distance colleague and he tried running it on his computer (Macbook Air) and it crashed violently. The problem appears to be in a multithreaded C component of the program. If I were to guess , it probably had something to do with deallocating an already freed pointer and therefore destabilizing the whole program. I checked and sent him a more safer version but he says the problem still persists. Here is the link to the relevant [code](https://github.com/haiderriazkhan/CANDLE/blob/master/ONLM_Mod.c).

Here is part of the error message:

```
Process:               JavaApplicationStub [12285]
Path:                  /Applications/ImageJ/ImageJ64.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
Identifier:            gov.nih.info.rsb.ImageJ
Version:               10.2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           JavaApplicationStub [12285]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-30 13:22:36.186 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        AC745C9B-736D-93B0-9896-25C03329CC79

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1D9C670A-85E4-4A80-9CA5-B73C5E6792B9

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       740 seconds

Crashed Thread:        22  Java: Run$_CANDLEMacro$

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000800

VM Regions Near 0x800:
--> 
   __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW /Applications/ImageJ/ImageJ64.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub

Application Specific Information:
Java information:
Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=100407080

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.65-b04-466.1 mixed mode macosx-amd64)

.
.
.

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
par new generation   total 49536K, used 905K [73f600000, 742bc0000, 744930000)
 eden space 44032K,   2% used [73f600000, 73f6dfa30, 742100000)
 from space 5504K,   0% used [742660000, 742662ca8, 742bc0000)
 to   space 5504K,   0% used [742100000, 742100000, 742660000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 456744K, used 274044K [744930000, 76073a000, 7fae00000)
concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 61252K, used 36701K [7fae00000, 7fe9d1000, 800000000)

Code Cache  [107001000, 107272000, 10a001000)
total_blobs=981 nmethods=394 adapters=549 free_code_cache=48669056 largest_free_block=6592

Virtual Machine Arguments:
JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Resources/LauncherSupport.jar -Xms256m -Xmx3000m -Dapple.awt.Antialiasing=false -Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=false -Dcom.apple.hwaccel=false -Dapple.awt.brushMetalLook=false -Dcom.apple.mrj.application.live-resize=true -Dcom.apple.smallTabs=true -Dcom.apple.mrj.application.growbox.intrudes=false 
Java Command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic
Physical Memory: Page Size = 4k, Total = 8192M, Free = 475M


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89041eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8904137b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89040bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b6956f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b692ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b6912b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff896a69bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff896a5f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
10  libawt.jnilib                   0x000000011222b86f -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8969bbf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  libawt.jnilib                   0x0000000112229f20 +[AWTStarter startAWT:] + 1495
13  libawt.jnilib                   0x000000011222989a -[CPerformer perform] + 93
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff91077d00 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8904fa01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89041b8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff890411bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89040bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.apple.JavaApplicationLauncher   0x00000001000060e4 startupJava(LauncherArgsStruct*) + 245
20  com.apple.JavaApplicationLauncher   0x0000000100008bc9 launchJavaApplicationWithJVMInfo + 1457
21  gov.nih.info.rsb.ImageJ         0x0000000100000b98 0x100000000 + 2968

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6f232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a3b2a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c264e 0x104803000 + 783950
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c255d 0x104803000 + 783709
6   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481618e 0x104803000 + 78222
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048bd2a6 0x104803000 + 762534
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048bce07 0x104803000 + 761351
9   com.apple.JavaApplicationLauncher   0x0000000100007da1 startJavaApplication + 7257
10  com.apple.JavaApplicationLauncher   0x0000000100006110 java_main_stub(void*) + 9
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: Java: Exception Handler Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e68f60 mach_msg_server + 468
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816f45 0x104803000 + 81733
4   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816f09 0x104803000 + 81673
5   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

.
.
.

Thread 12:: Java: Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c264e 0x104803000 + 783950
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c255d 0x104803000 + 783709
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816176 0x104803000 + 78198
7   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104aed18b 0x104803000 + 3056011
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
9   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
10  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: Java: Signal Dispatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6951a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b6463 0x104803000 + 734307
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b5f30 0x104803000 + 732976
3   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
5   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: Java: C2 CompilerThread0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c264e 0x104803000 + 783950
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c255d 0x104803000 + 783709
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816176 0x104803000 + 78198
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048bc4c5 0x104803000 + 758981
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b72af 0x104803000 + 737967
9   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
10  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
11  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: Java: C2 CompilerThread1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c264e 0x104803000 + 783950
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c255d 0x104803000 + 783709
6   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816176 0x104803000 + 78198
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048bc4c5 0x104803000 + 758981
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b72af 0x104803000 + 737967
9   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
10  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
11  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: Java: Low Memory Detector
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c264e 0x104803000 + 783950
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c255d 0x104803000 + 783709
6   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481620f 0x104803000 + 78351
7   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b9c9e 0x104803000 + 748702
8   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
9   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
10  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: Java: VM Periodic Task Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c2735 0x104803000 + 784181
3   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d7f86 0x104803000 + 872326
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048bb880 0x104803000 + 755840
5   libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: Java: AWT-Shutdown
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d8377 0x104803000 + 873335
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d80c6 0x104803000 + 872646
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a6303 JVM_MonitorWait + 156
7   libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x00000001000bbb0b JVM_MonitorWait + 59
8   ???                             0x00000001070bdd08 0 + 4413185288

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89041eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8904137b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89040bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8976e66b _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: Java: Java2D Disposer
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d8377 0x104803000 + 873335
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d80c6 0x104803000 + 872646
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a6303 JVM_MonitorWait + 156
7   libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x00000001000bbb0b JVM_MonitorWait + 59
8   ???                             0x00000001070bdd08 0 + 4413185288
9   ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
10  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
11  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
12  ???                             0x0000000107006d34 0 + 4412435764
13  ???                             0x0000000107001438 0 + 4412412984
14  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104899b54 0x104803000 + 617300
15  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5e8e 0x104803000 + 667278
16  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d80 0x104803000 + 667008
17  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d20 0x104803000 + 666912
18  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
19  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
20  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 21:: Java: AWT-EventQueue-0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d8377 0x104803000 + 873335
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d80c6 0x104803000 + 872646
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a6303 JVM_MonitorWait + 156
7   libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x00000001000bbb0b JVM_MonitorWait + 59
8   ???                             0x00000001070bdd08 0 + 4413185288
9   ???                             0x00000001070b1d7c 0 + 4413136252

Thread 22 Crashed:: Java: Run$_CANDLEMacro$
0   libONLM_Mod.dylib               0x0000000100407080 ONLM + 224
1   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005ab94c ffi_call_unix64 + 76
2   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005ab456 ffi_call + 630
3   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005a22f5 Java_com_sun_jna_Native_ffi_1prep_1cif + 1621
4   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005a2772 Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokeVoid + 34
5   ???                             0x0000000107011eee 0 + 4412481262
6   ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
7   ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
8   ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
9   ???                             0x0000000107006e8d 0 + 4412436109
10  ???                             0x0000000107006d34 0 + 4412435764
11  ???                             0x0000000107001438 0 + 4412412984
12  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104899b54 0x104803000 + 617300
13  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104899918 0x104803000 + 616728
14  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b1254 0x104803000 + 713300
15  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b246e 0x104803000 + 717934
16  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048b222e JVM_InvokeMethod + 358
17  libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x00000001000bfd7e JVM_InvokeMethod + 78
18  ???                             0x0000000107011eee 0 + 4412481262
19  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
20  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
21  ???                             0x0000000107006e8d 0 + 4412436109
22  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
23  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
24  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
25  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
26  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
27  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
28  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
29  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
30  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
31  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
32  ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
33  ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
34  ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
35  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
36  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
37  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
38  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
39  ???                             0x0000000107006d34 0 + 4412435764
40  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
41  ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
42  ???                             0x0000000107006d34 0 + 4412435764
43  ???                             0x0000000107001438 0 + 4412412984
44  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104899b54 0x104803000 + 617300
45  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5e8e 0x104803000 + 667278
46  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d80 0x104803000 + 667008
47  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d20 0x104803000 + 666912
48  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
49  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
50  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
51  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
52  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
53  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 23:: Java: org.python.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048c26a3 0x104803000 + 784035
3   libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104816600 0x104803000 + 79360
4   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d8377 0x104803000 + 873335
5   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048d80c6 0x104803000 + 872646
6   libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a6303 JVM_MonitorWait + 156
7   libjvmlinkage.dylib             0x00000001000bbb0b JVM_MonitorWait + 59
8   ???                             0x00000001070bdd08 0 + 4413185288
9   ???                             0x000000010700685a 0 + 4412434522
10  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
11  ???                             0x00000001070069b3 0 + 4412434867
12  ???                             0x0000000107001438 0 + 4412412984
13  libclient64.dylib               0x0000000104899b54 0x104803000 + 617300
14  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5e8e 0x104803000 + 667278
15  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d80 0x104803000 + 667008
16  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5d20 0x104803000 + 666912
17  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a5bbe 0x104803000 + 666558
18  libclient64.dylib               0x00000001048a59cf 0x104803000 + 666063
19  libclient64.dylib               0x000000010481607a 0x104803000 + 77946
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 24:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e694de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6864f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9416b04f CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 198
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9416af82 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b268 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152b1e5 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152941d thread_start + 13

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88e6e94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9152940d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 22 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
 rax: 0x0000000139399000  rbx: 0x0000000000000200  rcx: 0x0000000000000800  rdx: 0x0000000000000008
 rdi: 0x0000000100031280  rsi: 0x00000000000000a9  rbp: 0x00000001174ee850  rsp: 0x00000001174ee720
  r8: 0x0000000003000001   r9: 0x0000000000000003  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
 r12: 0x0000000000000008  r13: 0x000000000000000a  r14: 0xa900b50506ac8350  r15: 0x00000001174ee9f0
 rip: 0x0000000100407080  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000800

Logical CPU:     3
Error Code:      0x00000006
Trap Number:     14
```

The relevant machine:

```
Model: MacBookAir6,1, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 1.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.12f143
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is close to impossible for us to know the exact cause. However, to point out the most relevant parts of your error message. First you see this:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000800
```

which means that the program crashes due to a `SIGSEGV` signal (segmentation fault) when trying to acces the address `0x0000000000000800`.

We also see that it is thread 22 that triggers the crash from this part of the message:

```
Crashed Thread:        22  Java: Run$_CANDLEMacro$
```

Further down we can see what thread 22 is doing:

```
Thread 22 Crashed:: Java: Run$_CANDLEMacro$
0   libONLM_Mod.dylib               0x0000000100407080 ONLM + 224
1   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005ab94c ffi_call_unix64 + 76
2   jna1934359639328178547.tmp      0x00000001005ab456 ffi_call + 630
....
```

It seems your program is crashing in `libONLM_Mod.dylyb` in the `ONLM` method. The `+ 224` means that it is crashing at 224 bytes inside the `ONLM` method. If you have debugging symbols you can convert that to line number using `nm` and `addr2line` (thanks to Banthar).

Comment: `ONLM + 224` means at 224 byte inside `ONLM` method. If you have debugging symbols you can convert that to line number using `nm` and `addr2line`